# Variance of linear regression model with omitted variable bias

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, variance, linear-model, omitted-variable-bias

Suppose we have the following data generation process:
\begin{align*}
    U &= N_{U}\\
    X_{1} &= \alpha_{1}U + N_{1}\\
    X_{2} &= \alpha_{2}U + N_{2}\\
    X_{3} &= \alpha_{3}U + N_{3}\\
    Y &= \beta_{1}X_1 + \beta_{2}X_{2} + \beta_{3}X_{3} + N_{Y},
\end{align*}
with $(N_{U}, N_{1}, N_{2}, N_{3}, N_{Y})\sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

Suppose we estimate the following linear model $\hat{y} = \hat{\beta}_{1}x_{1}+\hat{\beta}_{2}x_{2}+\hat{u}$, where $\hat{u}$ are the estimated residuals. We know that the estimates for $\beta_{i}$ are biased because we omitted $x_{3}$ in the regression.

I am now trying to determine the variance of the model I estimated. So far, I have been grinding through a lot of algebra by defining $\sigma_{\hat{y}} = \mathbb{E}[(y-\hat{y})^{2}]=\mathbb{E}[y^{2}-2y\hat{y}+\hat{y}^{2}]$, and replacing $y$ for the true model that includes $x_{3}$.

Things start to get nasty on $\mathbb{E}[y\hat{y}]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\hat{y}^{2}]$, because $\hat{\beta_{i}}$ are biased estimates so they include covariances between covariates.

Am I tackling this problem correctly? Maybe I am using the wrong formula or not using a well-known simplification.

Comment: Actually, the estimates of $\beta_i$ are not biased because the omitted variable is not a confounder. The usual variance formulas apply.

Comment: @Noah Thank you for your comment. Although the omitted variable is not a confounder, it opens the backdoor path between $U$ and $Y$, so the estimates are biased. I wrote a couple of proofs in the comments before but I deleted them because they were only valid for single variable regression. I will work on a matrix proof of the bias and write in on a comment or the main post :)

Comment: I see, you're right. Sorry for the mistake.